# Validation using Yup to check array length --> error if length === 1

Tags: javascript, reactjs, yup

I have the following object:

```
{
    array: [1]
}
```

And the following code:

```
myArray: Yup.array().of(
    Yup.object().shape({
        name: Yup.string().max(255).required().label('Name')
    })
)
```

Now I check the name is required, I need to check if `myArray` has `length === 1` to return an error.

Answer (score 25):

You could use [`mixed.test(options: object)`](https://github.com/jquense/yup#mixedtestoptions-object-schema) if you just want to test `length === 1`:

```
myArray: array()
  .of(
    object().shape({
      name: string()
        .max(255)
        .required()
        .label("Name")
    })
  )
  .test({
    message: 'The error message if length === 1',
    test: arr => arr.length !== 1,
  })
```

**Demo:**

[image: Edit holy-http-e3y4e]

And [`array.min(limit: number | Ref, message?: string | function)`](https://github.com/jquense/yup#arrayminlimit-number--ref-message-string--function-schema) if you want to test `length === 0 | 1` :

```
myArray: Yup.array()
  .of(
    Yup.object().shape({
      name:Yup.string()
        .max(255)
        .required()
        .label('Name')
      })
  )
  .min(2, 'The error message if length === 0 | 1')
```

**Demo:**

[image: Edit happy-sea-dds1e]